# jQuery .data() does not work on buttons?

Tags: jquery

I have this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/37924/).  In it I try to set a data attribute on a button.  Doesn't work.

```
$("button").data("test", "tested");
```

using `.prop("date-test", "tested):` does not work.  It will work if I use `.attr()`.  Is this special to buttons in jQuery?

Comment: .data doesn't set attribute values. never has, never will.

Comment: This is not specific to buttons.  Any html element will yield the same result.  Always use `.attr()` when setting the value (because it is a data-attribute not a data-property).  You can retrieve already set values via `.data()`, it just doesn't work for setting values on the fly.

Comment: See also:  https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `attr(key)` will get the attribute on the element.  **The value will always be a String, if it exists.**
Calling `attr(key, value)` will set the attribute on the element, and will not update any jQuery cache.

Calling `data(key)` will get the data element out of the jQuery cache.  If it is not found, it will get the value from the attribute and cache it for future requests for it.  **It will also try to auto parse the string into whatever type it can, so the value will not always be a String.**
Calling `data(key, value)` will set the value in the cache, and will not update the attribute on the element.

```js
var $button = $('button');

//set the attribute on the element
$button.attr('data-test1', 'hi');

//First time call with attr get, value will be correct
//First time call with data get, value will be correct as it falls back to getting the attr value
console.log( 'Set with attr =>', $button.attr('data-test1'), $button.data('test1'));

//set the data value in the jQuery cache.  does not change any attribute
$button.data('test2', 'hi2');

//First time call with attr get, value will be undefined
//First time call with data get, value will be correct
console.log( 'Set with data =>', $button.attr('data-test2'), $button.data('test2'));

//modify the attr after data() has already been called
$button.attr('data-test1', 'new value');

//Second time call with attr get, value will be correct
//Second time call with data get, value will be incorrect as it has the previously cached value that is not updated with attr()
console.log( 'Set with attr =>', $button.attr('data-test1'), $button.data('test1'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Blah</button>
```

Comment: Thank you all.  I was starring at the `.data()` page for a long time and just never saw that the "signature" is "(ELEMENT, key, val)".  I went in with the assumption that `data` was like `attr` or `prop` so only saw what I expected to see.